# Addition of Second Hard Drive causes initramfs Shell at Boot

Tags: 17.10, wubi, initramfs

I added another hard drive recently to use as a backup drive. However, after doing that, upon restarting, it says: "ALERT! /host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!"
After unplugging it, it started as normal. My guess is that it was choosing disk sdb to boot from, for some odd reason. I then had an idea to try to fix it by plugging it in while Ubuntu was suspended and then running $sudo update-grub, but the problem persists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [root.disk not found](https://askubuntu.com/q/55830). Is the UUID of the partition with root.disk unique ? `sudo blkid`